# Como obter info de uma coluna do banco de dados através do método GET que recebo de outra página.

Tags: php, mysql, html5-audio

Sou novo em php e banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como faço para buscar no banco de dados o "nome", "senha" "email" através do id que recebo via _GET da pagina anterior e exibir na página que estou.

Para deixar mais claro. Tenho uma página onde tem uma tabela e nesta tabela tenho várias colunas e uma das colunas está um link chamado detalhes no qual abre uma página com mais detalhes do mesmo campo. no link detalhes envio através de _GET o id do meu campo. O que eu queria era que quando eu abrisse a pagina "detalhes" a nova tabela estivesse automaticamente com as informações do campo seleccionado na pagina anterior. Existe algum código que através do id recebido possa consultar as colunas especificas que antes não mostravam e exibir na nova página?

agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você quer. Ajuda muito se você incluir o código do que você já fez até agora (apenas o que é relevante para a pergunta).

Comment: Seria legal perguntar exatamente a etapa que está com dúvidas, pois da forma que está tem um monte de incógnitas, e me parece ter mais de um problema na mesma questão. Sugestão de leitura, para aumentar a chance de ter boas respostas no Stack Overflow em Português: [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Cara,

Eu recomendo você não passar o id de forma concreta (site.php?id=1).

Faça com que ele mande de forma criptografada, pode-se usar o "base64_encode" na hora que você inserir o código no link.Exemplo:

```
<a href="bacon.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode([id]); ?>" />
```

[Especificação do base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Deste modo irá gerar uma string no lugar do id.

Já na parte do detalhamento, você pode buscar os dados com essa query:

```
$sql = "SELECT [nome],[senha],[email] FROM [tabela] WHERE [id_automatico_da_coluna] = '".base64_decode($_GET[id])."'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
```

Onde aqui você usa o base64_decode(), para decodificar aquela string que veio criptografada.

[Especificação do base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: "criptografado" (entre aspas)

Comment: é kk. Não é bem uma criptografia, mas é só o modo de falar. :)

Comment: criptografado não e sim codificado, trazendo uma segurança a mais para a aplicação. base64 é uma criptografia de mão dupla aonde você consegue retornar a informação existente diferente de MD5 que é uma criptografia de mão única. Então @ChristianPassold esta correto quando fala em criptografia já Andrey precisa estudar um pouco mais, não devemos satirizar algo que esta correto talvez sem o devido conhecimento.

Comment: Entendo que há a boa intenção em postar uma resposta, mas creio que o conteúdo não responde à pergunta de fato, e não vejo onde o base64 ajuda nestes casos, primeiro por ser a coisa mais simples de decodificar online, segundo por ser visualmente fácil identificar o encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você tem que ter uma conexão com o banco de dados, depois basta fazer a consulta e percorrer os registros retornados caso eles existam.

Da uma olhada nessas funções mysql_connect, mysql_query, mysql_fetch_assoc

O PHP tem uma boa documentação em Português.
Veja aqui [Funções do PHP para usar o MYSQL](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php)

Se a sua duvida diz respeito a SQL seria assim:

```
SELECT nome, senha, email FROM tabela WHERE id = '$_GET['id']';
```

Você está com duvida no PHP ou no MySQL?

Comment: A primeira versão da resposta tinha mais a ver com o que está sendo perguntado. E vale lembrar do Bobby: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Eu não entendi se a duvida dele é com o PHP ou com o MySQL

Comment: MySQL, vou pesquisar no link que você me enviou. valeu

Comment: Se não conseguir resolver, edita e tua pergunta e coloca o que tu tens, que vai nos ajudar a te ajudar. kkk  Abraço